# Clickable PDFs in rxvt

Tags: pdf, rxvt, evince

I would like to open PDFs (say, with `evince`) by clicking in the terminal.

The setup is `urxvt` in Fedora 19 here, but if `urxvt` cannot do this, can you let me know which terminal emulators can. I got URL detection working by putting:

```
urxvt*perl-lib: /usr/libi64/urxvt/perl/
urxvt*perl-ext-common: default,matcher
urxvt*matcher.button: 1
urxvt*url-launcher: /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

Into my `~/.Xdefaults` and running `xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults`, so hopefully there is some similar solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: What do you want to click on? A URL like `http://example.com/something.pdf`? Or just a file name that's displayed on the terminal? Is the problem to get `xdg-open` to launch `evince`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer. One has to look at

```
/usr/lib64/urxvt/perl/matcher
```

and there they give examples. My usecase is to do

```
find . | grep -i something
```

and get a bunch of lines like

```
./foo/bar/something1.pdf
./bar/foo/something-and-else.pdf
```

so that adding the two lines

```
urxvt*matcher.pattern.1:  \\B(./\\S+?).pdf
urxvt*matcher.launcher.1: evince $1.pdf
```

seems to do the job. I am quite clueless about perl regular expressions, so
this is not ideal. E.g.,

```
./foo/bar/something.pdf.trashinfo
```

will be caught (it shouldn't - it is not a PDF file!), whereas

```
./foo/barname barsurname - something.pdf
```

will not be caught due to the whitespaces. Perhaps somebody can write something more elegant.

Thanks to everyone who took interest in this, cheers!